# Displaying results from row_number 2 and next

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have written this Query

```
SELECT 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY b.s_id) as RN,
g.code as De, 
f.code as Ar
from a_c a
left join ne_a b ON b.n_a_id = a.n_a_id
left join Sh d ON d.s_id = b.s_id
left join A g ON g.a_id = a.d_a_id 
left join A f ON f.a_id = a.a_a_id 

where b.s_id = 'MHJIX'
ORDER BY b.s_id
```

and it gives me result as

```
RN  De  AR

1   S   D
2   D   G
3   G   J
```

I want to display results which starts from Row_Number 2 and onwards. 
Row_numbers can always change. In above example there are 3 rows in total, but it can be 5 rows in some other example.
How can I display results which starts from row_number 2 and onwards?
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like this (CTE - Common Table Expression):

```
;WITH YourCTE AS
(
   SELECT 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY b.s_id) as RN,
      g.code as De, 
      f.code as Ar,
      b.s_id
   FROM a_c a
   left join ne_a b ON b.n_a_id = a.n_a_id
   left join Sh d ON d.s_id = b.s_id
   left join A g ON g.a_id = a.d_a_id 
   left join A f ON f.a_id = a.a_a_id 
   where b.s_id = 'MHJIX'
)
SELECT * FROM YourCTE
WHERE RN >= 2
ORDER BY s_id
```

Basically, you need to "wrap" your query that contains the `ROW_NUMBER()` ranking function into a sub-query or CTE so that you can then reference that new "row_number" column in the outer query (to use it to limit your end result set).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CTE as Marc suggested, or you can use a derived table:

```
SELECT  b.RN,
        g.code as De, 
        f.code as Ar

FROM    a_c a
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT n_a_id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY b.s_id) AS RN FROM ne_a) b ON b.n_a_id = a.n_a_id
        LEFT JOIN Sh d ON d.s_id = b.s_id
        LEFT JOIN A g ON g.a_id = a.d_a_id 
        LEFT JOIN A f ON f.a_id = a.a_a_id 

WHERE   b.s_id = 'MHJIX' AND b.RN >= 2
```